# Azure AD not showing Manager in M365 Users

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365

I do not know what is going on with the interface Microsoft 365 Users, the Manager attribute is not being shown. However in Azure AD the manager is always there. I thought M365 Users was a mirroring of the users in Azure AD, but this is not the case, maybe I did not activate something.
I appreciate from now your help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

***I tested in my environment. I can see manager attribute successfully in M365 admin center.***

In M365 admin center, we can find users from Azure Active directory, Dynamic 365 apps, Exchange, Teams, SharePoint etc., which are supported by **`Microsoft`**.

As Azure AD is one among them, we can find all Azure AD users in M365 admin center.

**I tried adding manager attribute in Azure AD for specific user.**

[image]

**The manager attribute successfully got reflected in M365 admin center**.

[image]

Make sure to sign in to **`M365 admin center`** and **`Azure portal`** with **same admin account**.

In Azure portal, check if the user is in ***correct domain/directory*** if not switch the directory and check.

**Reference:**
[Microsoft 365 user management versus Azure Active Directory](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/microsoft-365-user-management-versus-azure-active-directory/ba-p/2192320#footerContent)